# Rotation Estimation between two images

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, homography, 3d-reconstruction, pose-estimation

I want to get the rotation between two images taken from the same camera (known intrinsic). I have a nearly perfect pure rotation!

I use findhomography but if there is a little translation movement I get four results. Is there a way to force the homography that it assumes it is a pure rotation?

**EDIT:** Picture sample: the camera is rotating
[image]

Comment: camera/scene rotation (3D) or image rotation (2D)? Post sample images if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can decrease the dimension of the problem a bit by using [cv::estimateRigidTransform](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#Mat%20estimateRigidTransform(InputArray%20src,%20InputArray%20dst,%20bool%20fullAffine)) and passing `false` for `fullAffine` argument. This will make it `translation, rotation, and uniform scaling` but there is is not pure rotation method in OpenCV.